# Pocketsphinx - specify a language model

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed pocketsphinx, but I don't know how to use it. I try to run python script:

```
rosrun pocketsphinx recognizer.py
```

and have the following output:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1395053854.598681] Please specify a language model file or a fsg grammar file.
```

What shall I do? How can I specify this model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140811/pocketsphinx---specify-a-language-model/) by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You indeed need to build a language model.

Go to [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm) tutorial page for this. There is also a web tool which is very helpful in this [Language model web service](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html).

The tutorial explains further instructions on how to convert and use the model

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on 2014-03-23**:
Thank you! I found language model from Voxforge and tried to run recognizer.py with parameters -dict /home/sphinx/msu_ru_nsh.dic -lm /home/sphinx/msu_ru_nsh.lm.dmp . But nothing changed. The output of command showed me that pocketsphinx already uses wsj model, but if there exists any model, why the error I noticed appears always?